# Overriding rydurham/sentinel route paths in Laravel 5

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5, laravel-routing, cartalyst-sentinel

I am using the rydurhmam/sentinel package in Laravel 5.0.x and I cannot change how the default mysite.com/profile route is handled.

In my routes.php file I have declared `Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController');`

When I call php artisan route:list I get:

```
| GET|HEAD | profile                | sentinel.profile.show | Sentinel\Controllers\ProfileController@show    | sentry.auth  |
| GET|HEAD | profile/create         | profile.create        | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@create  | sentry.auth  |
| POST     | profile                | profile.store         | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@store   | sentry.auth  |
| GET|HEAD | profile/{profile}      | profile.show          | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@show    | sentry.auth  |
| GET|HEAD | profile/{profile}/edit | profile.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@edit    | sentry.auth  |
| PUT      | profile/{profile}      | profile.update        | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@update  | sentry.auth  |
| PATCH    | profile/{profile}      |                       | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@update  | sentry.auth  |
| DELETE   | profile/{profile}      | profile.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@destroy | sentry.auth  |
```

And you'll notice the first profile route is handled by the Sentinel Controller found within the vendor package file.

The sentinel config file only allows you to turn off routing in its entirety, so is there anyway to override selected controllers or am I SOL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
In config/sentinel.php

```
  'routes_enabled' => false,
```

in your routes.php

```
include(dirname(with(new ReflectionClass('Sentinel\SentinelServiceProvider'))->getFileName()) . '/../routes.php');
```

and declare your routes as normal in routes.php file after include
and that should work fine.

let me know.

Comment: I just want to add a prefix to Sentinel Group Controllers. Any idea?

Comment: I am getting `Class SignatureDish\Http\Controllers\Sentinel\Controllers\SessionController does not exist` error, Do you know how to resolve this